# Expand event data aggregated to yearly summaries for regions to panel data for all regions

Tags: stata

I have a large event data set, that I have summarized to provide yearly aggregates for an event characteristic "success" across geographic regions, i.e. provinces in Italy. However in some provinces no event took place, so I would like to add these provinces for each year and set the success variable to 0.

Example dataset:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int year str15 province_str float success
1981 "Bergamo" 0
1981 "Bologna" 0
1982 "Bergamo" 0
1982 "Bologna" 0
1983 "Bergamo" 0
1983 "Bologna" 0
1984 "Bergamo" 0
1984 "Bologna" 0
end
```

So, for example, I am looking to add the province "Roma" for all years to the dataset.

I have looked at `expand` and `fillin`, but it does not work.

The end should look like this:

```
input int year str15 province_str float success
1981 "Bergamo" 0
1982 "Bergamo" 0
1983 "Bergamo" 0
1984 "Bergamo" 0
1981 "Bologna" 0
1982 "Bologna" 0
1983 "Bologna" 0
1984 "Bologna" 0
1981 "Roma" 0
1982 "Roma" 0
1983 "Roma" 0
1984 "Roma" 0
end
```

If "Roma" is not present in the event data set, `fillin` will not create it.

Comment: "didn't work" is a poor problem report without showing the code you tried or what happened (or didn't happen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a tempfile containing the missing observations for the `province_str` variable, save it, load the original dataset and append it to the original  dataset:

```
tempfile province_data

* Add two new provinces
local provinces "Roma Ferrara"
* Set observations to a count of the provinces
set obs 2
* Add the other variables needed for appending
gen str province_str = ""
gen year = 1984
gen success = 0

* * Loop through each string in the local macro
foreach str of local provinces {
    * Replace the value of province_str at position i
    replace province_str = "`str'" in `i'
    * Increment the count variable
    local ++i
}

* Now, `province_data` holds the dataset with all provinces
save "`province_data'"

* Merge datasets
use `italy_data', clear
append using `province_data'

* Use fillin to create the dataset
fillin year province
```

Comment: OK, but the creation of the file to be `append`ed could be rewritten much more concisely.

Comment: I am not a tempfile kind of guy. Coming from R, frames are much more intuitive for me. But if you have suggestions / improvements, feel free to edit. The important functionality of my code is that I can add more provinces to the local without having to changes anything else.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand any of those extra comments. You don't need to use tempfiles or local macros at all. The point is that you need to add extra observations before the `fillin` will work as you wish. Whether you want to type in extra observations or just `append` an extra dataset is up to you and to be decided on other grounds.  Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

`fillin` can't replicate what isn't there. If an entire panel is absent, minimally one observation must be supplied before `fillin` can do what you want.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int year str15 province_str float success
1981 "Bergamo" 0
1981 "Bologna" 0
1982 "Bergamo" 0
1982 "Bologna" 0
1983 "Bergamo" 0
1983 "Bologna" 0
1984 "Bergamo" 0
1984 "Bologna" 0
1984 "Roma"    0 
end

fillin province_str year 
replace success = 0 if missing(success)
sort province_str year 

list, sepby(province_str)

     +-------------------------------------+
     | year   provin~r   success   _fillin |
     |-------------------------------------|
  1. | 1981    Bergamo         0         0 |
  2. | 1982    Bergamo         0         0 |
  3. | 1983    Bergamo         0         0 |
  4. | 1984    Bergamo         0         0 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  5. | 1981    Bologna         0         0 |
  6. | 1982    Bologna         0         0 |
  7. | 1983    Bologna         0         0 |
  8. | 1984    Bologna         0         0 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  9. | 1981       Roma         0         1 |
 10. | 1982       Roma         0         1 |
 11. | 1983       Roma         0         1 |
 12. | 1984       Roma         0         0 |
     +-------------------------------------+
```

EDIT

Following the OP's own answer, here is a demonstration that if you wish you can put the extra observations into another dataset to be `append`ed.

```
clear
input int year str15 province_str float success
1981 "Bergamo" 0
1981 "Bologna" 0
1982 "Bergamo" 0
1982 "Bologna" 0
1983 "Bergamo" 0
1983 "Bologna" 0
1984 "Bergamo" 0
1984 "Bologna" 0
end

save maindata, replace 

* this could be part of the same script
* this extra dataset could be -save-d as such
clear 
input str7 province_str year success 
Roma 1984 . 
Ferrara 1984 .
end 

append using maindata 

fillin year province

replace success = 0 if missing(success)
```

Comment: If province_str does not contain the province "Roma", won't  `fillin` will just create the combinations for existing provinces? In my example, `fillin` would just create all cross-combinations for the provinces "Bergamo" and "Bologna" for the years 1981-1984. Thus, for the dataset above, it would do nothing.

Comment: Just read around a bit! https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0500500117 explains.